# Add static view of Leaflet in Rmarkdown pdf output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, r-leaflet

I have an RMarkdown that I'd like to knit to HTML and PDF. The notebook contains a LeafLet map that I can see fine in the HTML preview but it's completely ignored in the PDF output. By this I mean, the code gets executed but no map is displayed bellow the code chunk in the PDF output.

I read in the RStudio docs that, [if a dynamic element is included in a static output format (PDF), a screenshot of the output should be included](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-14.html)

This is my RMarkdown header:

```
---
title: "Análise dos dados do Hydra"
always_allow_html: yes
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_notebook: default
---
```

And this is the code that generates the leaflet map

```
m <- leaflet(pontos_geo) %>%
addTiles() %>%
addCircleMarkers(~lon, ~lat, radius = 2, color = ~pal(ordem)) %>%
addLegend('bottomright', pal = pal, values = ~ordem)
m
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing webshot and PhantomJS: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/interactive-documents.html

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. But I'm halfway there. Now the PDF shows my points but the tiles that come from OpenStreetMap are not showing up. I suspect it has something to do with proxy because I have the same problem when I knit my Rmd to HTML. It works on RStudio browser but not in firerox

Comment: @YihuiXie is there any reason for this not to work in rstudio.cloud ?  I installed webshot and phantom_js() without any warnings. This simple code works well with html output, but it fails to produce a pdf: https://rstudio.cloud/project/419891